# How to find the conserved quantities of $\phi^4$ model?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, soliton-theory

Consider
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\partial^2_t\phi-\partial^2_x\phi=\phi -\phi^3,\: \ (x,t) \in \Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
the $\phi^4$ model, often used
in quantum field theory and other areas of physics. It can be found [here](https://www.ams.org/jams/2017-30-03/S0894-0347-2016-00870-6/), Ref. [1].

How to calculate the conserved quantities for this model?

---

[1] Michał Kowalczyk, Yvan Martel and Claudio Muñoz: Kink dynamics in the $\phi^4$ model: Asymptotic stability for odd perturbations in the energy space, *J. Amer. Math. Soc.* 30 (2017), 769-798. [doi:10.1090/jams/870](https://doi.org/10.1090/jams/870)

Comment: Multiply by $\varphi$ and integrate by parts?

Comment: @mattos And what do I conclude with that?

Comment: That there is a conserved quantity, which is the same as that given by Qmechanic below (under suitable boundary conditions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lagrangian density for the system in 1+1D spacetime is
$$ {\cal L}~=~\frac{1}{2}(\partial_t\phi)^2 -\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x\phi)^2-{\cal V}, \qquad {\cal V}~= ~\frac{1}{4}\phi^4-\frac{1}{2}\phi^2. $$
We can now calculate the conserved quantities as [Noether charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) for the symmetries of the action functional. Poincare symmetry with Lie algebra [$iso(1,1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group#Poincar%C3%A9_algebra) is generated by 2 spacetime translations and 1 boost. The corresponding 3 Noether charges are energy, momentum & boost,
$$\begin{align} 
H~=~& \int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x~{\cal H}, \qquad 
{\cal H}~=~\frac{1}{2}(\partial_t\phi)^2 +\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x\phi)^2+{\cal V},\cr 
P~=~& \int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x~{\cal P}, \qquad 
{\cal P}~=~\partial_t\phi~\partial_x\phi,\cr
B~=~& \int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\mathrm{d}x~{\cal B}, \qquad 
{\cal B}~=~t{\cal P}-x{\cal H}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: But in [1] he quotes that $E= \int \frac{1}{2}\phi_t^2+\frac{1}{2}\phi_x^2+\frac{1}{4}(1-\phi^2)^2$ is the 'energy of the $\phi^4$ model. Is that energy one of the conserved quantities? It is similar to what @EditPiAf gave us below.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno If we change the potential sector's sign in Qmechanic's answer to achieve the Hamiltonian density, we get$$\mathcal{H}=\frac12\phi_t^2+\frac12\phi_x^2+\frac14(\phi^4-2\phi^2).$$(BTW, Qmechanic, your quartic coefficient should be $\frac14$). Adding an irrelevant constant of $\frac14$ to that, we can rewrite the final polynomial as $\frac14(1-\phi^2)^2$ as claimed.

Comment: Thanks @J.G. Corrected.

Comment: @Qmechanic I only skipped through the paper because this is beyond me but something caught my eye, they mention repeatedly the fermi golden rule but it doesn't look anything like what appears on [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi's_golden_rule) , would you know this is the same thing in different settings or just some kind analogy? Thank you

Comment: @Daniel D. Thanks for the feed back. It indeed would be interesting to see the connection to the standard version of Fermi's golden rule. I don't have anything more to say at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Define the energy
$
E(t) = \frac12\! \int_{\Bbb R}  {\phi_t}^2 + {\phi_x}^2 \,\text d x
$
as usually done for wave equations. Thus,
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\text d}{\text d t}E(t) &= \int_{\Bbb R}  {\phi_t}\phi_{tt} + {\phi_x}\phi_{xt} \,\text d x \\
&= \int_{\Bbb R}  {\phi_t}(\phi_{xx} + \phi - \phi^3) + {\phi_x}\phi_{tx} \,\text d x \\
&= \int_{\Bbb R} ({\phi_t}\phi_{x})_x + {\phi_t} (\phi - \phi^3) \,\text d x \\
&= \int_{\Bbb R}  \big(\tfrac12\phi^2 - \tfrac14\phi^4\big)_t \,\text d x \\
&= -\frac{\text d}{\text d t}D(t)
\end{aligned}
with $D(t) = \frac14\! \int_{\Bbb R} \phi^2(\phi^2-2) \,\text d x$. Therefore, the energy $E +D$ is conserved. Note that the energy found in the article is also conserved. Indeed, it is of the form $E+C$ with $C(t) = \frac14\! \int_{\Bbb R} (1-\phi^2)^2 \,\text d x$; the densities corresponding to $C$ and $D$ differ only by a constant.

Comment: So, $E+D$ is one of the conserved quantities?

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno Yes, the energy $E+D$ with $D = \tfrac14 \int \phi^4 - 2 \phi^2 \text dx$ is conserved. But the energy density is defined up to a constant. Indeed, the energy $E+C$ with $C = \tfrac14 \int (1-\phi^2)^2\text d x$ found in the paper is also conserved.